# Facing problem Value cannot be null. Parameter name: g

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
           db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

           var b = db.tbl_User.Where(a => a.ActivationCode == new Guid(id)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (b != null)
          {
```

The problem is on this line:

```
var b = db.tbl_User.Where(a => a.ActivationCode == new Guid(id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

my code is

```
    public ActionResult VerifyAccount(string id)
    {
        bool Status = false;
        using (DriveAwayEntities db = new DriveAwayEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            var b = db.tbl_User.Where(a => a.ActivationCode == new Guid(id)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (b != null)
            {
                b.IsEmailVerified = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                Status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Request";
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Status = true;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you instantiate your `Guid` outside of the LINQ query? e.g.

```
Guid guid = new Guid(id);
var b = db.tbl_User.Where(a => a.ActivationCode == guid).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would have expected a slightly different error, but I suspect it's Entity Framework telling you that `new Guid(id)` isn't a valid database operation.